# Sencha touch - Launch not invoked

Tags: extjs, touch, cordova, tablet, launch

I'm developing an app with Sencha Touch and i'm using phonegap to wrap it into native app and to use native **APIs**.

My app was working great, but suddenly after some hours changing some things, I built it to test it on my tablet. But it does not launch (it only shows the loading indicator), in spite of launching perfectly on desktop browser.

I've put some `alert()` in my code and I discovered that the launch function on `app.js` is not being invoked...
My `index.html` is being executed perfectly.

Everything was working great but now I dont know whats happening...
Can anybody save me?

Comment: Did you check your index.html? Is the app.js file included in that?

Comment: Hi there. I'm using Sencha Touch 2.1.1 and in this version the app.js is only included on app.json.

Comment: Resolved!
The problem was that JS is assynchronous. So it worked on my browser because my application was executed in a different order than in my tablet. I had a global variable in a view that should not be there. Thank you.